# Could we provision additional BU if we have Corporate edition?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Could we provision additional BU if we have Corporate edition?  Based on what I remember it used to be possible years ago to but now I don't find a clear indication that BUs are available under any license but Enterprise. What is your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical reason that would prevent adding additional BUs for Corporate edition. It comes down to what has been licensed for your account and if you've purchased the additional BUs item.

You may be confused if you're seeing the "Compare Editions and Top Features" on the pricing page (https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/marketing-cloud/email/) as it seems to indicate that managing multiple business units isn't supported, however that's actually displaying what comes with the edition.

If you scroll down you'll see the "Download The Full Edition Comparison Chart). In that chart you'll see the "Additional Business Units" is supported for Corporate.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. I've already found that part of pricing as well.